# socket io insert data to table Azure Mobile App Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I am working with socket io, Azure Mobile app and azure database, the socket io will save my message to Azure database.

```
 io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('send_message', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            c.saveMessage(data);
        });
}
```

but as I know about the azure mobile app, I have to use req.azureMobile to communication with the database, so i don't know how to pass the request to socket io or create a context can communicate with the database

Comment: Have you solved this issue? AFAIK, you can't pass the request to socket io or create a context can communicate with the database. You could follow the approaches in my answer to meet your requirement for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to use req.azureMobile to communication with the database, so i don't know how to pass the request to socket io or create a context can communicate with the database

For your requirement, I checked it on my side and tried to follow [30 DAYS OF AZURE MOBILE APPS](https://shellmonger.com/30-days-of-azure-mobile-apps-the-table-of-contents/) for possible approach to meet your requirement, but without luck in the end.

For your requirement, I assume that you could follow the approaches below:

- Just leverage [THE HTTP TABLE INTERFACE](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/27/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-13-the-http-table-interface/) exposed by Azure Mobile Apps middleware and explicitly call the related table endpoint for saving your messages.
- Use other packages (e.g. [tedious](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tedious)) and write your SQL statement to directly communicate with your SQL Server database. Details you could follow [Use Node.js to query an Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-nodejs).

Comment: yes, I can not pas the request to socket io so I made a request from socket io to communicate with the database, but it isn't best solution

Comment: I did not find a way to directly retrieve the existing table reference and execute the related SQL statement, you could add your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/568069-azure-mobile-app) or add your issue at [Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/issues).